# sftp - "protocol error: mtime.sec not present" when using /usr/sbin/nologin

Tags: permissions, security, sftp

I am trying to use sftp to pull a file from a remote server.

Both client and server-side users are created with `adduser --system` and their shell is `/usr/sbin/nologin`. The users are called `legit-backup`.

Public-key authorisation has been configured for the client user to have SSH access to the server as a user of the same name. When I try to pull down the file `/home/legit-backup/test` a file using the command `sudo -u legit-backup scp legit-backup@<remote-server>:~/test`, I receive the error `protocol error: mtime.sec not present`, no files copy down.

If I change the remote user's shell to /bin/bash then sftp works as normal.

I wan to use `/usr/sbin/nologin` for security reasons, the user should not be able to have SSH access other than sftp, is it possible?

Comment: You might consider using `ForceCommand internal-sftp` instead of setting the nologin shell. See for example [Is it possible to grant users sftp access without shell access? If yes, how is it implemented?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503346/65304)

Comment: Use sftp command instead, it should work